# rails Getting an DEPRECATION WARNING in my log file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Hi I am getting the following warning in my log file. Hence newbie I would like to know what is this warning and how to solve it one.

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Calling #find(:all) is deprecated. Please call #all directly instead. You have also used finder options. These are also deprecated. Please build a scope instead of using finder options. (called from user_rating at /home/raj/Desktop/webapp/app/controllers/company_ratings_controller.rb:73)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Relation#all is deprecated. If you want to eager-load a relation, you can call #load (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).load`). If you want to get an array of records from a relation, you can call #to_a (e.g. `Post.where(published: true).to_a`). (called from user_rating at /home/raj/Desktop/webapp/app/controllers/company_ratings_controller.rb:73)
```

Here is my company_ratings_controller at 73 line:

```
def user_rating   
    company_id = current_user.profile.companies.map(&:id)
    rating = current_user.company_ratings.find(:all,:conditions=>["user_id = ? and company_id IN (?)",current_user.id,company_id]) [line 73]

    end
```

Please tell what is my problem what is causing me all the errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to "[Ruby on Rails 4.0 Release Notes](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/4_0_release_notes.html)" for deprecations, changes and new additions to the framework.

To fix the deprecation, replace the following line from your `user_rating` method:

```
rating = current_user.company_ratings.find(:all,:conditions=>["user_id = ? and company_id IN (?)",current_user.id,company_id])
```

with:

```
rating = current_user.company_ratings.where("user_id = ? and company_id IN (?)",current_user.id,company_id)
```

Comment: nk you Now I understood

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should call it using `where` instead of `find`

```
rating = current_user.company_ratings.where(
           user_id: current_user.id,
           company_id: company_id)
```